# Create highlight effect on hover an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I tried to make highlight effect on each `<a>` element while I hover on each `div` element but it doesn't work and console shows this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined
> at highlight_function"

[image]

```
function highlight_function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("a").style.background = "#80ff00"
};

document.getElementsByTagName("div").addEventListener("mouseover", highlight_function())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` is an array, and you are trying to set style on the array and not in each element.

You should either make a for loop to change background style of each element or add a style tag like `a {background: "#80ff00"}`.

But you can't define style to an array like this

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <a href="#"> something</a>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    function highlight_function() {
        const a = document.querySelector('a');
        a.style.background = "#80ff00"
    }

    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    div.addEventListener('mouseover', highlight_function);

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think background property will work on an `<a>` tag. Try doing this in your function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").style.color="#80ff00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is you can try this

```js
function highlight_function() {
  document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = "#80ff00";
};
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <a id="a" onmouseover="highlight_function()">Hell</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you make this call
`document.getElementsByTagName("a")`
it will return to you collection of html elements so there is no style property
you can use for loop through it

```
for(var a of document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
  a.style.background="#80ff00";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add highlight effect or change the background color by adding the CSS as follows:

```css
p:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="hometown">I live in Pakistan</p>
```